# ¿Cómo lograr un respaldo empaquetado de archivos en forma profesional vía Cronjob?

Tags: linux, shell, crontab, cron

Necesito respaldar en forma diaria, una carpeta de archivos pdf. Se trata de una cantidad grande de archivos por lo primero lo empaqueto en `Gzip` y luego elimino el anterior archivo `Gzip`. Para lograr esto tengo el siguiente código en un archivo `.sh` que lo ejecuta un cron todos los días a las 5:00 AM:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Empaqueto los archivos y lo dejo en la carpeta archivos_empresas
cd /var/www/html/sistema/respaldo/respaldopdf && tar -cpzf $(date +%d%m%Y)-respaldo.tar.gz  /var/www/html/sistema/archivos_empresas

#Luego busco el anterior gz y lo elimino 
find /var/www/html/sistema/respaldo/respaldopdf/*.gz -mtime +0 -exec rm {} \;
```

Todo bien, pero sucede algo curioso: No siempre elimina el archivo anterior y lo peor es que no logro encontrar el patrón para preverlo. Por lo que todos los días tengo que revisar si fue eliminado o no el archivo para hacerlo en forma manual con un RM ya que al ser muy pesado utiliza mucho espacio en el disco.

Alcances:

1.- Esto se solucionaría manteniendo el mismo nombre de archivo ya que se reemplazaría, pero no quiero hacer eso ya que, por seguridad, necesito que primero se genere el nuevo y si se genera bien que elimine el anterior.

2.- Se que el comando `-mtime +0` debería ser `-mtime +1` pero de esa forma me lo elimina el archivo del dia de ante de ayer no el de ayer.

Lo que necesito es hacer un respaldo profesional (esta solución que hice parece que es medio aficionada ). Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: En la carpeta donde dejas el respaldo hay algo más o está sólo este fichero .tar.gz? Si sólo guardas este puedes eliminar todo el contenido de la carpeta y una vez eliminado hacer el nuevo (El orden inverso al que lo haces ahora)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Posible solución**

Cambia la linea `find /var/www/html/sistema/respaldo/respaldopdf/*.gz -mtime +0 -exec rm {} \;` por
`find /var/www/html/sistema/respaldo/respaldopdf/*.gz -daystart -mtime 1 -exec rm -f {} \;`

**Mejorando tu script**

> pero no quiero hacer eso ya que, por seguridad, necesito que primero se genere el nuevo y si se genera bien que elimine el anterior.

En tu script, se genere o no el backup de seguridad, borra (o lo intenta) el backup anterior, no tienes nada que controle si se ha ejecutado bien el anterior comando (esto se soluciona añadiendo un `&&` y el comando después de `tar -cpzf $(date +%d%m%Y)-respaldo.tar.gz  /var/www/html/sistema/archivos_empresas`). También comentar que el cd que haces es innecesario, ya que puedes (y debes) utilizar la ruta absoluta en el tar.

También comentar que si quieres hacer tu script más 'profesional', tienes que considerar mantener los permisos en el backup (`--same-owner`, `-p`, etc). Guardar un log de los errores (`2> error.log` por ejemplo). También plantear hacer backups diferenciales, incrementales,... es buena idea, para evitar hacer únicamente backups completos (que ocupan más).

**Como dejaría yo el script** (se puede mejorar mucho más, pero más o menos una idea)

```
#!/bin/sh
#Empaqueto los archivos y lo dejo en la carpeta archivos_empresas + se borra el anterior backup
tar -cpzf /var/www/html/sistema/archivos_empresas/$(date +%d%m%Y)-
respaldo.tar.gz /var/www/html/sistema/respaldo/respaldopdf/* 2> /var/log/errores-backup.log && find /var/www/html/sistema/respaldo/respaldopdf/*.gz -daystart -mtime 1 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Gracias ! lo voy a revisar a la tarde y te comento

Comment: Bueno , funcionó muy bien por lo que te agradezco la respuesta. Saludos!